# How does TimeSlider Control work in OpenLayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2, timeslider

I would like to use the [TimeSlider control](https://github.com/metno/openlayers-timeslider) of Openlayers in version 2 for WMS-Time, but there is no documentation or examples.

Could someone help me understand how this control works?

Comment: Do you have a WMS-T server to test against. I can explain how it works, but it would be nice to be able to do it against a real WMS-T server.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.